# Problem starting GRASS GIS in elementary OS 5.1

Tags: slingshot

After installing grass gis in elementary OS 5.1 the item in the application menu does not work. The application can be started from the terminal but its appearance is anomalous with an annoying duplicate transparent window that should not be present (The application starts correctly in Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome and Linux Mint 13.3 Cinnamon).
This is the .desktop file present in / usr / share / applications:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=GRASS GIS 7
GenericName=Geographic Information System
GenericName[ar]=نظام المعلومات الجغرافي
GenericName[az]=Coğrafi informasiya sistemi
GenericName[bg]=Географска информационна система
GenericName[bs]=Geografski informacioni sistem
GenericName[ca]=Sistema d'informació geogràfica
GenericName[cs]=Geografický Informační Systém
GenericName[de]=Geographisches Informationssystem
GenericName[el]=Σύστημα Γεωγραφικών Πληροφοριών
GenericName[es]=Sistema de Información Geográfica
GenericName[et]=Geoinfosüsteem
GenericName[eu]=Geografia-informazioko sistemen
GenericName[fa]=سامانه اطلاعات مکانی
GenericName[fi]=Maantieteellinen Tietojärjestelmä
GenericName[fr]=Système d'Information Géographique
GenericName[gl]=Sistema de información xeográfica
GenericName[he]=מערכת מידע גאוגרפית
GenericName[hi]=भूगोलीय_सूचना_प्रणाली
GenericName[hr]=Geografski informacijski sustav
GenericName[hu]=Földrajzi információs rendszer
GenericName[hy]=Աշխարհագրական տեղեկատվական համակարգ
GenericName[id]=Sistem informasi geografis
GenericName[is]=Landfræðilegt upplýsingakerfi
GenericName[it]=Sistema Informativo Geografico
GenericName[ka]=გეოინფორმაციული სისტემა
GenericName[lt]=Geografinė informacinė sistema
GenericName[lv]=Ģeogrāfiskā informācijas sistēma
GenericName[mk]=Географски информационен систем
GenericName[ml]=ജി.ഐ.എസ്.
GenericName[nl]=Geografisch informatiesysteem
GenericName[nn]=Geografiske informasjonssystem
GenericName[no]=Geografiske informasjonssystemer
GenericName[pl]=System Informacji Geograficznej
GenericName[pt]=Sistema de Informação Geográfica
GenericName[ro]=Sistem Informatic Geografic
GenericName[ru]=Геоинформационная система
GenericName[sh]=Geografski informacijski sistem
GenericName[sk]=Geografický informačný systém
GenericName[sl]=Geografski informacijski sistem
GenericName[sr]=Географски информациони систем
GenericName[sv]=Geografiskt Informationssystem
GenericName[th]=ระบบสารสนเทศภูมิศาสตร์
GenericName[tr]=Coğrafi bilgi sistemi
GenericName[uk]=Геоінформаційна система
GenericName[uz]=Geografik axborot tizimi
Icon=grass
TryExec=/usr/bin/grass74
Exec=grass74
Terminal=true
Keywords=gis;spatial;geospatial;database;remote sensing;hydrology;vector;raster;visualization;maps;wms;wfs;ogc;osgeo;
Categories=Education;Science;Geoscience;Geography;
```

but I was unable to find anomalies or errors.

[image]

These are the files in / usr / bin involved in starting the application:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
From a terminal 'GTK_CSD=0 grass74' when launching the app. Please do it and report back if it worked.

Thanks.

-Aldo

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly by launching it from the terminal! Now it remains to be understood why starting from the application menu does not work. Starting the program In Ubuntu or Mint from dock or the application menu, first open the terminal and then the graphical automatically . In elementary OS the terminal does not start and therefore neither the graphical interface, any idea about it?

Comment: There's a bit of a reading you can do here: https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/244 - TL;DR, a bug ;)

You can edit the ".desktop" file (Shortcut) and add that parameter under the "exec" that way this variable is passed at the moment of double clicking the icon.

Comment: Thanks again for the tips, but before setting the variable in the .desktop file to avoid the graphic problem (and GTK_CSD=0 solve this part of the problem) I should solve the problem that the application doesn't start using the application menu but perhaps I had not clearly exposed the problem (or split the problem in two questions): from the terminal the application starts but from applications menu it doesn't start at all. Could it be because of the io.elementary.terminal emulator?

Comment: Try removing the  "TryExec=/usr/bin/grass74" line from the desktop file.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: What about adding the full path to the binary file in the "exec=" field?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. I don't know how to check if this problem could derive from the fact that the application starts from the terminal (which in elementary OS is different than in Ubuntu and Mint)

Comment: As a workaround you can create a bash script to run the app. Basically in the EXEC= field you would use your bash script path (i.e.: /home/user/script.sh).

Then your .sh script should just be used to launch the app:

------start
#!/bin/bash
GTK_CSD=0 grass74
-------end

Save it, 'chmod +x script.sh'

and that should work

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can create a bash script to run the app. Basically in the EXEC= field you would use your bash script path (i.e.: /home/user/script.sh).

Then your .sh script should just be used to launch the app:

```
#!/bin/bash 
GTK_CSD=0 grass74
```

Save it, 'chmod +x script.sh' and that should work –

Comment: I created the grass74.sh file; made the file executable; checked in the terminal with ./grass74.sh ok works. Changed the .desktop file with  Exec=/home/andrea/Applicazioni/grass74.sh but unfortunately doesn't works: neither the terminal opens nor the application starts

Comment: Add  (if you havent already) the following line to your .desktop file : "Terminal=true"

Comment: The existing .desktop file already has the terminal = option set to true. I also tried to create a new launcher with the AppEditor utility (terminal = true) but unfortunately it doesn't work either.